# How do I get the TOP 1 appearing value by count and name desc from a UNION of 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I need the TOP 1 string from 2 columns, the value should be returned ordered by number of appearances and by name descending. This is in SQL-Server.

Here's an example table:

```
------------------------------
|   Column1    |   Column2   |
------------------------------
|     John     |   Michael   |
------------------------------
|    Thomas    |    John     |
------------------------------
|    Martin    |    Rick     |
------------------------------
|    David     |   Thomas    |
------------------------------
|     John     |   Martin    |
------------------------------
```

What the resulting order should look like:

```
----------------------------
|   Column1    |   COUNT   |
----------------------------
|     John     |     3     |
----------------------------
|    Martin    |     2     |
----------------------------
|    Thomas    |     2     |
----------------------------
|     David    |     1     |
----------------------------
|    Michael   |     1     |
----------------------------
|     Rick     |     1     |
----------------------------
```

What the result should look like:

```
----------------------------
|   Column1    |   COUNT   |
----------------------------
|     John     |     3     |
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select top 1 c, count(*) [Count]
from
(
   select column1 c
     from ATable
   union all
   select column2
     from ATable
) a
group by c
order by count(*) desc
```

To get most used name and choose alphabetically first among them:

```
select top 1 c, count(*) [Count]
from
(
   select column1 c
     from ATable
   union all
   select column2
     from ATable
) a
group by c
order by count(*) desc, c
```

If you want to do the same but with one column only:

```
select top 1 column1, count(*) [Count]
  from ATable
group by column1
order by count(*) desc, column1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), as of SQL 2005:

```
-- Example Data
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Column1 VARCHAR(10), Column2 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @Data VALUES ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('C', 'A'), ('D', 'E'), ('A', 'D')

SELECT TOP 1 Name, COUNT(*)
FROM @Data d
    UNPIVOT (Name FOR Col IN (Column1, Column2)) AS unpvt
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #t (Column1 nvarchar(50), Column2 nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO #t (Column1, Column2)
VALUES ('John', 'Michael')
,('Thomas', 'John')
,('Martin', 'Rick')
,('David', 'Thomas')
,('John', 'Martin')



;WITH cte (Column1)
AS
(
    SELECT Column1
    FROM #t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Column2
    FROM #t
)



SELECT TOP 1
        Column1
        ,COUNT(*) as [COUNT]
FROM cte
GROUP BY Column1
ORDER BY [COUNT] DESC
```